# Match a value and paste data in the next available cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to easily add text to all cells that contain a match. The problem i have is i don't want to overwrite any cells, so if B2 contains anything then paste the data in the next available blank cell.

When i run the macro i want to add `Range("E2").value` in every next blank cell that matches data in `Range("D2")` In the examples case for every 1.1 add X

The X is where any of the new data should be added to.
Example:

```
 A | B | C | D 

1.1 | 1.0 | X

1.2 |

1.3 |

1.4 |

1.1 | X

1.1 | 0.9 | 1.0 | X

1.2 |

1.3 |

1.1 | 1.0 | X
```

This is the code that i've been working with. So far it will find and add successfully the first time, but when it runs again it adds the value i want to For i 1 to X amount.

```
Sub onelineCODE()

Dim i As Integer
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

Set SrchRng = Range("D3:D10")
For Each cel In SrchRng
    For i = 1 To 20
        If cel.Offset(, i).Value > 0 And InStr(1, cel.Value, Range("D2")) > 0 Then
            cel.Offset(, i + 1).Value = Range("E2")
        ElseIf InStr(1, cel.Value, Range("D2")) > 0 Then cel.Offset(, 1).Value = 
            Range("E2")
        End If
    Next i
Next cel

End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
Sub stackOverflow()
    Dim i As Integer, searchValue As Double, fillValue As String
    Dim SrchRange As Range, cel As Range, offRange As Range
    searchValue = 1.1
    fillValue = "X"
    Set SrchRng = Range("D3:D10")
    For Each cel In SrchRng
        If cel.Value = searchValue Then
            Set offRange = cel.Offset(0, 1)
            Do While Not IsEmpty(offRange)
                Set offRange = offRange.Offset(0, 1)
            Loop
            offRange.Value = fillValue
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Hope it helps, happy coding...